# Showing real time progress number of download in WPF DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, c#-4.0, prism

Currently i got some problem with WPF downloader application. i got a few stack of files shown in wpf datagrid. all files have to download one by one depend on priority. i want to show how many percentage had been downloaded in one of it's columns.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your problem? Have you done some code? Can you copy it?

Comment: get the file size.check the number of bytes downloaded.separate thread then use dispacher. add more details to get an answer

Comment: So, you have described what do you want. And where is the question?

Comment: later will upload my issue